# BayesSearchCV with KerasClassifier: "Invalid parameter" Error When Tuning Hyperparameters

Tags: python, machine-learning, lstm

I'm trying to tune the hyperparameters of a Keras model using `BayesSearchCV` from Scikit-Optimize and `KerasClassifier` from SciKeras. However, I'm encountering a `ValueError` stating that the hyperparameters are invalid parameters for `KerasClassifier`.

I've structured my code as follows:

```
# Import necessary libraries
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from skopt import BayesSearchCV
from skopt.space import Real, Categorical, Integer
import numpy as np

# Model building function
def create_model(neurons, dropout, optimizer, learning_rate, num_features):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, input_shape=(None, num_features), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(LSTM(neurons, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    opt = get_optimizer(optimizer, learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])  
    return model

# Hyperparameter space
params = {
    'neurons': Integer(25, 200),
    'dropout': Real(0.1, 0.6),
    'optimizer': Categorical(['Adam', 'SGD', 'RMSprop']),
    'learning_rate': Real(0.0001, 0.5)
}

# Initialize KerasClassifier
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model)

# Setup BayesSearchCV
bayes_search = BayesSearchCV(
    estimator=classifier,
    search_spaces=params,
    n_iter=50,
    cv=4,
    verbose=10,
    n_jobs=-1
)

# Error occurs during the fitting process
bayes_search_result = bayes_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

When running this code, i encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter dropout for estimator KerasClassifier. This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasClassifier constructor: `KerasClassifier(dropout=0.4380397544384568)` Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`
```

It seems that **`BayesSearchCV`** is trying to set the **`dropout`** parameter directly on the **`KerasClassifier`**, which isn't compatible with how hyperparameters are handled in Keras models.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to correctly set up hyperparameter tuning for a Keras model using **`BayesSearchCV`** and **`KerasClassifier`**. Thank you!